# Time out exception with Selenium WebDriverWait

Tags: python, selenium

all,

I'm pretty new to Python and Selenium so, I hope you are forgiving! I know this has been asked before. I'm trying to scrape data from this page but not being successful. I get a timeout error even though my wait time is pretty large. Here is my modest code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
driver.header_overrides = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://superrare.com/features/series-4" 
response = driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
element = WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "FeaturedArtistName-sc-jssh89-2 iTyMhR")))

print(html)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues here:

1. You are using a classname that has a lot of randomization in it. Chances are that it may change.  So I tried to make it a little robust by taking only the static part of the classname.
2. There are 13 elements with the classname `FeaturedArtistName-sc-jssh89-2 iTyMhR` ( and I am presuming that you are trying to wait for all of them), but you are asking the driver to wait for the `presence_of_element` whereas it should be `presence_of_elements`. So, I tweaked your code a bit, and in a jiffy, I got the result.

This is the line I tweaked:
element = `WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class,'FeaturedArtistName')]")))`

Output (I am not showing all the output here to save space)

```
<html lang="en" class="js-focus-visible wf-roboto-n5-active wf-roboto-n3-active wf-roboto-n7-active wf-roboto-n4-active wf-materialicons-n4-active wf-active"><head><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://widget.intercom.io/widget/d3gh4rmg"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script id="twitter-wjs" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script><script>!function(){var t=window,e=t.Intercom;if("function"==typeof e)e("reattach_activator"),e("update",t.intercomSettings);else{var
```

Comment: Thank you @Anand Gautam. It seems to work to some extent indeed but it pulls the whole page source. I'll keep working to see if I can make it pull more specific tags. Perhaps I need to insert a call to a specific div? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized my code was printing the whole page print(html) rather than printing that call print(element). Silly me!

Comment: I knew when posting that you were printing the whole page source, but I thought you needed it as is. Maybe this what you are looking for to start with.

`for i in element:
    print(i.text)`

This prints the text of the featured artist DOM line that it is inspecting (in easy words, the artist names)

Comment: exactly! I just added this to my code and I got exactly what I wanted

`for elem in element:
     print(elem.text)`